# Check color of the rows of the datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

I basically want to check if a certain row contains white color then it should not be replaced in the datagridview otherwise if it contains any other color then the text in that row can be replaced but I don't know how to check that condition in this scenario.

This is the code.

```
private void button9_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var original = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
  var clone = original.Clone();
  var ordinal = original.Columns["Stringtext"].Ordinal;
  for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     var values = original.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            values[ordinal] = ((values[ordinal].ToString()).ToLower())
                .Replace(textBox6.Text.ToLower(), textBox7.Text);
            clone.Rows.Add(values);
  }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = clone;
        string filterBy;
        filterBy = "Stringtext Like '%" + textBox7.Text + "%'";
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please add info for the color part, the above code shows nothing why it should have a different color, Also you have a `CellFormatting` event where you can set the format as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all cells in the `DataGridView` and check the background color of the cell you can do something like

```
for (int c = 0; c < dataGridView.ColumnCount; c++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < dataGridView.RowCount; r++)
    {
        if (dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != Color.White)
            // Do your update here
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.